# jQuery .remove() not working?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a group of dynamic select options. The ajax calls are working with the `on change` function, but for some reason, the `.remove()` method does not seem to be working. When I change the institution, the new departments are appended, but the existing departments are not removed.

I'm certain there's a glaring error here somewhere, but I've stared at this so long I can't find it.  Thanks in advance for taking the time to lend your fresh eyes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="/ajax">

        <label for="institution">Institution</label>
            <select class ="form-control" id="institution" name="institution">
                <option value="">-- select one --</option>
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                <option value="three">three</option>
            </select>            

        <select id="departments">
            <option>-- choose one --</option>
        </select>

        <select name="blocks" id="blocks">
            <option value="">-- choose one --</option>
        </select>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <br /><br /><br />
<a href="#" id="tester">which value?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $departments = $('select#departments');
    $('select#institution').on('change', function () {
        $('option.department-dynamic-option').remove();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/ajax/institution/' + this.value + '/departments',
            success: function (depts) {
                $.each(depts.result, function (i, dept) {
                $departments.append('<option class="department-dynamic-option" value="' + dept.department_id + '">' + dept.department_name + '</option>')
            });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: if you put a break point where you call .remove(), how many objects is jquery returning for `$('option.department-dynamic-option')`?

Comment: @Mike_G good idea.  I've figured out how to add the breakpoint in chrome, but still looking for the output of `objects returned`. Stay tuned.

Comment: Are you sure the ajax request isn't just returning more than you think it is?

Comment: @Ryan If you break on the `$('option.department-dynamic-option').remove();` in Chrome, just add `$('option.department-dynamic-option')` to your watch list and it should be evaluated when you hit the break.  If the length of the object is 0, then it didn't find any elements matching your query.

Comment: @Mike_G thanks for that. It's returning the appropriate number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the jquery html function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $departments = $('select#departments');
$('select#institution').on('change', function () {
    $departments.html('');//Clean the inner html
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ajax/institution/' + this.value + '/departments',
        success: function (depts) {
            $.each(depts.result, function (i, dept) {
            $departments.append('<option class="department-dynamic-option" value="' + dept.department_id + '">' + dept.department_name + '</option>')
        });
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: No luck. Thanks anyway though.  That's a good trick to have up the sleeve.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="/ajax">

        <label for="institution">Institution</label>
        <select class ="form-control" id="institution" name="institution">
            <option value="">-- select one --</option>
            <option value="one">one</option>
            <option value="two">two</option>
            <option value="three">three</option>
        </select>   

        <select id="departments">
            <option>-- choose one --</option>
        </select>

        <select name="blocks" id="blocks">
            <option value="">-- choose one --</option>
        </select>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>


<script>

$( '#institution' )
  .change(function () {
    var $departments = $('select#departments');
    $('.dynamicdepts').remove()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ajax/institution/' + this.value + '/departments',
        success: function (depts) {
            $.each(depts.result, function (i, dept) {
                $departments.append('<option class="dynamicdepts" value="' + dept.department_id + '">' + dept.department_name + '</option>')
            });
        }
    });

  });
$( 'select#departments')
    .change(function () {
        var $blocks = $('select#blocks');
        $('.dynamicblocks').remove()
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ajax/department/' + this.value + '/blocks',
        success: function(blocks){
            $.each(blocks.result, function(i, block){
                $blocks.append('<option class="dynamicblocks" value="' + block.block_id + '">' + block.block_name + '  --  (' + block.block_start + ' to ' + block.block_end + ')</option>')
            });
        }
    });
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```